# Get Download Link for Public Shared File From DropBox

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I have been trying to get a file that is publicly accessible from Dropbox. It is not shared to my account but can see the folder and download it fine. Can also access the folder via https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder and see below for each file.

```
[1] => Array
            (
                [.tag] => file
                [name] => sharedFile.xlsx
                [parent_shared_folder_id] => XXXX
                [id] => id:XXXX
                [client_modified] => 2023-03-17T09:12:53Z
                [server_modified] => 2023-03-17T09:12:53Z
                [rev] => XXXX
                [size] => 170784
                [sharing_info] => Array
                    (
                        [read_only] => 1
                        [parent_shared_folder_id] => XXXX
                        [modified_by] => dbid:XXXX
                    )

                [is_downloadable] => 1
                [content_hash] => XXXX
            )
```

A lot of answers are suggesting I need to build a temporary link from this info however using the ID in the path just returns path not found. Have tried a fair few different approaches but have had little luck.

e.g. https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/sharing/get_file_metadata
Seems to show:

```
{
"error_summary": "access_error/invalid_file/...",
"error": {
    ".tag": "access_error",
    "access_error": {
        ".tag": "invalid_file"
    }
  }
}
```

Unsure if using the id: from original response is the way to go with these publicly accessible folders. Am getting a little frustrated that I can pull the files list but there is no simple way of just downloading the file. I can download a zip of the whole folder however by just adding dl=1 to the end of the shared folder without any authentication however want to just get individual files preferably.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Dropbox shared link to the folder, to download any particular file inside the folder based on the Dropbox shared link to the folder, you should use [/2/sharing/get_shared_link_file](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-get_shared_link_file). Set `url` to the shared link for the folder and `path` to the relative path of the file inside the linked folder.